# AS3 - Accessing subclass of subclass

Tags: actionscript-3, subclass

Im making this game, and I really want to access a "subclass of subclass". So I have something like this: MainClass > MonsterLibrary > SampleMonster.

I want to add this Sample Monster from MainClass, but I have to use it through MonsterLibrary, so I dont have to add monster by monster at my MainClass. Every monster respawn would be written in MonsterLibrary class.

I guess it should be something like this.

```
public class MainGame extends MovieClip {

    public function MainGame() {
        var mylibrary:MonsterLibrary = new MonsterLibrary();
        mylibrary.MonsterLibrary();
```

Main class.

```
public class MonsterLibrary extends MovieClip {

    #all var here.#

    public function MonsterLibrary(){
        var monster:SampleMonster = new SampleMonster(330,250);
        addChild(monster);
    }
```

MonsterLibrary class.

```
public class SampleMonster extends MonsterLibrary{

    public function SampleMonster(startX:Number, startY:Number) {

        //SETTING STARTING LOCATION
        x = startX;
        y = startY;
```

SampleMonster class.

I know Im doing it wrong, but I have no idea how to make this work. I keep getting this error ->
1061: Call to a possibly undefined method MonsterLibrary through a reference with static type MonsterLibrary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that error because you're trying to directly call the constructor of `MonsterLibrary`:

```
public function MainGame()
{
    var mylibrary:MonsterLibrary = new MonsterLibrary();
    mylibrary.MonsterLibrary(); // <- wrong
    ...
}
```

The `MonsterLibrary()` function is the constructor of the `MonsterLibrary` class and it's called automatically when you use the `new` operator to create a new instance of the class.

If you want your `MonsterLibrary` class to act as a monster factory (a class that creates monster objects), create a new function that returns a monster:

```
...
public function CreateMonster ( sType:String ):SampleMonster
{
    var oMonster:MovieClip = null; // you can use BaseMonster instead of MovieClip

    if ( sType == "SampleMonster" )
    {
        oMonster = new SampleMonster ( ... );
        ... // initialize the monster here
    }

    ...
    return ( oMonster );
}
...

// get a monster and add it to the stage
var oMonster:MovieClip = oMonsterLibrary.CreateMonster ( "SampleMonster" );

oStage.addChild ( oMonster );
```

Note that `MonsterLibrary` doesn't need to extend MovieClip - it really doesn't need to extend any type (other than `Object`) since (I assume) it's not a visual object. Its purpose is to be a factory, not to be on the screen. `oStage` in the code above is your top-level display object - it could be the actual stage or a `DisplayObject` that acts as your stage.

The `SampleMonster` type shouldn't extend `MonsterLibrary` - a particular monster is not a library. Your monsters should derive either directly from `MovieClip` or (better) from a common base monster class; something like:

```
public class BaseMonster extends MovieClip
{
    ...
}
```

Then your `SampleMonster` can derive from this base monster:

```
public class SampleMonster extends BaseMonster
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: If you check my answer, that's because you are adding `monster` to the `MonsterLibrary` Display List, but MonsterLibrary is not on the Display List of `MainGame`, so it's not on the stage.

Comment: Yea, I see what I was missing! Thanks bro.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused at what you are trying to accomplish.

Are you looking to  have the MonsterLibrary return a monster every time you call a method ?

ie you could have a method in MonsterLibrary class like this :

```
public function getMonster():SampleMonster
{
     var monster:SampleMonster = new SampleMonster(330,250);
     return monster;
}
```

Then your MainGame might look like this :

public class MainGame extends MovieClip {

```
public function MainGame() {
    var mylibrary:MonsterLibrary = new MonsterLibrary();
    var newMonster:SampleMonster = mylibrary.getMonster();
    addChild(newMonster);
```

Going further you could have a parameter for the `getMonster` method to specify a monster type.

for example :

```
public function getMonster(monsterType:int):Monster
{
   // create the appropriate monster and return it
}
```

Keep in mind that in your code adding the monster to the Display List of the `MonsterLibrary`, means it will never be seen UNLESS you add `MonsterLibrary` to the Display List of `MainGame`

Also you have `SampleMonster` extending `MonsterLibrary`, which is not going to work.

`SampleMonster` should probably extend `MovieClip` or `Sprite` or if you intend on having multiple monsters you'd want to have a base `Monster` Class that any specific monster might extend.

Comment: Cant I have more than one monster though? Tried to create a new var in getMonster() but didnt work. something like:
var monster2:SampleMonster = new SampleMonster(330,250);
     return monster2;

Comment: agreed, he specifies the way to set up the monster classes. I was giving you an example of how to go about creating a method in which MonsterLibrary would return a monster. @xxbbcc went the extra mile to code it for you. :)  I think we were both assuming what you wanted to do.

Comment: I didn't fully code it for you, I was giving you the basic concept that I thought you were going for. He coded it out for you, which follows the concept I was specifying. I am assuming you have a basic idea of how OOP works.